# Python - Finding max value in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello I am new to Python and I encountered some problems when generating the maximum value from the nested dictionary.

The original dict:

```
gradebooks = {'business analytics': {'Alice': 95, 'Troy': 92}, 'Python programming': {'James': 89, 'Charles': 100, 'Bryn': 69, 'Alice': 100}, 'R programming': {'Troy': 93, 'James': 100, 'Charles': 88}}
```

The new dict I want to generate:

```
{'business analytics': 95, 'Python programming': 100, 'R programming': 100}
```

I used the following code but cannot generate the maximum value:

```
ISOM_gradebooks = {course: v for course, name in gradebooks.items() for key, v in name.items()}
print(ISOM_gradebooks)
```

Any solutions to this, thank you.

Comment: `{k: max(v.values()) for k, v in gradebooks.items()}`

Comment: We expect you to make an honest attempt to solve the problem before posting here.  Finding the max value is documented well in many places.

Comment: @Prune I would say they did make an honest attempt. They showed their dict comprehension in their question, it wasn't correct, but at least they tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> {key: max(value.values()) for key, value in gradebooks.items()}
{'business analytics': 95, 'Python programming': 100, 'R programming': 100}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get the max values of each category:

```
outputDict = {}

# This will loop on each key and value of your gradebooks dictionary
for k,v in gradebooks.items()
    maxVal = 0
    # This will loop over the grades of each student
    for grade in v.values():
        if grade > maxVal:
            maxVal = grade
    # Update your dictionary with the value of the maxVal of your subject k
    outputDict[k] = maxVal
```

Let me know if this helps!